# Struggling with understanding proof by contradiction

Tags: logic

I'm struggling with understanding proof by contradiction. So, I understood proof by contradiction as written below.

Want to prove "$p$ is true". First, assume that "$p$ is false". Show that this assumption leads to a contradiction e.g. $q$ is true and $q$ is false at the same time. Therefore, "$p$ is true".

So I understand "$p$ is false" leads to a contradiction and therefore "$p$ is false" cannot be true. But I don't understand why this has to lead "$p$ is true" i.e. I'm confused why "$p$ is false" being wrong has to mean "$p$ is true". Is it just nature of mathematics that has to be either true or false? Why can't it be like "$p$ is false" is wrong but "$p$ is true" is also wrong?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8Q7HjMr This might help you. It is taken from Harold R. Jacobs' Geometry book.

Comment: This rule is often part of the definition of (a proof system for) classical propositional/first-order logic. It is *not* "just [the] nature of mathematics". In the scenario I just described, it is simply assumed. Truth table or Boolean algebra semantics validate it. Contrarily, constructive logics explicitly do *not* have this rule, and, correspondingly, they have different notions of semantics (e.g. Heyting algebra semantics) which don't validate it.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is it just nature of mathematics that everything has to be true or false?"

Yes. This is the [principle of bivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence).

Answer (score 2):

You use the assumption that $p$ is false to prove something you know is false, a contradiction. Thus the assumption that $p$ is false is wrong.

The only remaining possibility is that $p$ is true.

$p$ is a statement, it can only be true or false but not both. The sentence, "She is a student." (with no reference to a specific person) is not a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the assertion $P$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P\Rightarrow false$. Thus instead of proving $P$ you prove $\neg P\Rightarrow false$; you assume that $\neg P$ holds and then show that this leads to a logically false assertion which amounts to the contradiction.

For instance, show that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.
To prove this, assume the contrary, $\sqrt 2$ is rational. Then $\sqrt 2 = p/q$ where $p,q$ are relatively prime integers. From here one can derive a contraction, an assertion which is logically false.

Comment: Your example is *not* a proof by contradiction in the sense that the OP means or that you describe. Your example is something else often called negation introduction. You are showing $\neg P$ given $P\to\bot$, *not* $P$ given $\neg P\to\bot$. "Irrational" means "not rational". To give an idea as to the difference, negation introduction is often taken as a primitive rule in constructive logic whereas adding proof by contradiction produces classical logic, so these are *very* different rules.